# Using defaultdict function in verb tags counting

Tags: python, collections, spacy, defaultdict

Could you please explain why the **defaultdict** function does not define **verbs** in the code following? Googling tells me that the syntax is fine. Please help! Thanks in advance :)

## My code

```
import spacy
from collections import defaultdict
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
!pip install pandas==0.24.2 --user
import pandas as pd

def calculate_the_word_types(df):
  verbs = defaultdict(calculate_the_word_types)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
  doc = nlp(row["text"])


for v in map(lambda x: x.lemma_, filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)):
  verbs[v] += 1
  df.at(i, "nr_verb", len(list(map(lambda x: x.text,
                                                 filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)))))

return df
verbs
```

## Error code

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7e7c626bb331> in <module>()
     13 
     14 for v in map(lambda x: x.lemma_, filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)):
---> 15   verbs[v] += 1
     16   df.at(i, "nr_verb", len(list(map(lambda x: x.text,
     17                                                  filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)))))

NameError: name 'verbs' is not defined
```

Comment: Is your posted code has the `correct indentation` as shown here?

Comment: Is this really what you indenting looks like? It seems like everything after `def calculate_the_word_types(df):` is supposed to be *inside* the function.

Comment: you have two (or three) mistakes. (1) wrong indentations - you define `verbs` inside function but rest of code is outside function. (2) you define function but you never execute it. (3) `verbs` is local variable which exists only inside function but at the end you want to get value from this variable outside function - you have to `return verbs` and  get it `verbs = calculate_the_word_types(df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_value()` function is deprecated.

As replacement, you can use ".at" like this: df.at["YOURINDEX", "YOURCOLUMN"] = "YOURVALUE".
Also, you have issue on this line `verbs = defaultdict(calculate_the_word_types)`
initialize with 0 since it will act as counter.

And fix your indentation

working code -

```
import spacy
from collections import defaultdict
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
!pip install pandas==0.24.2 --user
import pandas as pd

def calculate_the_word_types(df):
    verbs = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    # count all tokens, but not the punctuations
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        doc = nlp(row["text"])

        # count only the verbs
        for v in map(lambda x: x.lemma_, filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)):
            verbs[v] += 1
        df.at[i, "nr_verb"] = len(list(map(lambda x: x.text, 
                                        filter(lambda x: (x.pos_ == 'AUX') | (x.pos_ == 'VERB'), doc)))) 

    return df


# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['hello there', 'I love Tatooine', 'I hate sands']})

# print the dataframe with verb count
print(calculate_the_word_types(df))
```

Output -

```
        text      nr_verb
0   hello there     0.0
1   I love Tatooine 1.0
2   I hate sands    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, @ahmedshahriar! But when I run the code, it shows nothing. So I typed 'df' and it gave me the same data frame as the initial one. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @Sangeun I updated the code with an example, fixed the indentation problem, check it